# PHP/JavaScript post to top?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a comment system written in PHP and JavaScript but each time I post the comment goes to the bottom. How do I make it appear at the top?

Here is my code:

The PHP code:

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE perma_id = '$permalink' ORDER BY `date` DESC" );
$count = mysql_num_rows( $sql );
?>

<h2 class="comments"><?php echo $count; ?> Comments</h2>

<div id="flash"></div>

<ol id="update" class="timeline">

<?php
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $sql ) ) {
    $userSql = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `id` = '$row[userid]'" );
    $userRow = mysql_fetch_assoc( $userSql );
    $name = $userRow[ 'userid' ];
    $comment = $row[ 'comment' ];
    $cDate = $row[ 'date' ];
    $icon = $userRow[ 'icon' ];
?>
<li class="box">
    <div class="left"><a href="<?php echo $site_url . '/wall/' . $name; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $site_url . '/' . $icon; ?>"/></a></div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="name"><a href="<?php echo $site_url . '/wall/' . $name; ?>"><?php echo $name;?></a> said...</div>
        <div class="date"><?php echo date("M d, Y g:i a", $cDate); ?></div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="comm">
            <div class="inside">
                <?php echo $comment; ?>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
<?php
}
?>
```

The JavaScript code:

```
$(function() {
$('.com_submit').click(function() {
    var comment = $("#comment").val();
    var user_id = $("#user_id").val();
    var perma_id = $("#perma_id").val();
    var dataString = { comment: comment, user_id: user_id, perma_id: perma_id };
    if(comment=='') {
        alert('Please Give Valid Details');
    }
    else {
        $("#flash").show();
        $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="../images/ajax-loader.gif" align="left" /> Loading Comment');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../commentajax.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $("ol#update").append(html);
                $("ol#update li:first").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#flash").hide();
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
}); 
});
```

I have `li:first` but it does not make it at the top

Comment: Pull them out of the database in a different order? What have you done to narrow down this issue? You have three completely distinct technologies here.

Comment: Databases have this magical `order by` option that lets you tell them how to sort the data... if you want newest comments first, then have your query tell the DB to sort by posting date and make the newest entries come first....

Comment: It's not how they are displayed in the loop. It's when I post the comment and receive the callback, the comment goes at the bottom of the loop under all the previous comments. I would like the new one to appear at the top.

Comment: @MarcB I already have the query ordering by date in a descending order. Displaying previous comments is not the problem here. It's the new post appearing underneath rather than at the top. I read somewhere that `li:first` would make it at the top and `li:last` would display at the bottom. However it is not doing so.

Comment: `li:first` is just a css pseudo-class to apply to only the first `<li>` in a list. It has nothing to do with ordering the position of the list elements. CSS itself cannot reorganize the order of the elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.prepend()` instead of `.append()`

Your `:first` fade in is working, it's just already visible. But remember that's only a jQuery selector.

Comment: Thank you the prepend() worked. Thank you to everyone else who helped :)

Answer (score 0):

.append always goes to the end.  i usually copy the contents of the ol, append it to the returned dataString, then put it back in the ol.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `.append(html)` with `.prepand(html)`

Answer (score 0):

I think it is happening because when you call append(html) in your javascript, the output is appended to the end of the update div... of course would be useful if you also post your HTML (the div code)